# Can I paste as plain text from Word and keep Bold, Italic buttons enabled in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I would like my text from Word to be stripped of all formatting when pasting into CKEditor 4.7.3. When I have the Bold or Italic buttons enabled, CKEditor will allow Bold and Italic to remain when pasting from Word. If I remove the buttons from CKEditor, Bold and Italic formatting is removed.

http://jsfiddle.net/xfvrA/472/

```
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    forcePasteAsPlainText: true,
    removePlugins: 'PasteFromWord',
    toolbar : [
    { name: 'document', items: [ 'Source', '-', 'NewPage', 'Preview', '-', 'Templates' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText',  '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic' ] }

],
    on: {
        change: function( evt ) {
            console.log( evt ); 
            CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( '<p style="color:red">Editor contents changed!</p>' ).appendTo( CKEDITOR.document.getBody() );
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that works for me is to remove all tags by using replace in the paste event.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
  ev.editor.on( 'paste', function( evt ){
    evt.data.dataValue = evt.data.dataValue.replace( /<[^>]*?>/g, '' );   
  } );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3312njyu/1/